# how to Check for dhclient in Directadmin

Tags: centos, dhclient

I have installed `CSF firewall` in `CentOS 6 64-bit` on `Directadmin`

`dhclient` appears to be running which suggests that the server is obtaining an IP address via DHCP. This can pose a security risk. You should configure static IP addresses for all ethernet controllers

how to fix this?

Comment: Speak to the people who provide the server and ask them ? Then if it is using dhcp obtain a fixed IP address from them.

Comment: I have root server , and i know my ip adress and i have even ipv4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main ethernet board is eth0 You should check the file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0. This will tell you if your system is using a fixed ip address or a DHCP derived ethernert address e.g. for a fixed IP address you'll have something like

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=10.0.1.27
...
```

and for DHCP it will be something like

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
```

There is more information on the network configuration files [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html).